# Can't cannocilazie "home/user/Maildir"

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, email, postfix

I just started learning ubuntu and trying to set up mail system (To use roundcube)
I am using online tutorial, to set up Postfix.
Did everything like in tutorial, but are stuck here:

Copy info from tutorial:

Send the email by piping a string to the mail command. Adjust the command to mark your Linux user as the recipient:

```
echo 'init' | mail -s 'init' -Snorecord username
```

You should get the following response:

```
Can't canonicalize "/home/sammy/Maildir"
```

This is normal and will only show during this first message. We can check to make sure the directory was created by looking for our ~/Maildir directory:

```
ls -R ~/Maildir
```

You should see the directory structure has been created and that a new message file is in the ~/Maildir/new directory:

```
Output
/home/username/Maildir/:
cur  new  tmp

/home/username/Maildir/cur:

/home/username/Maildir/new:
1463177269.Vfd01I40e4dM691221.mail.example.com

/home/username/Maildir/tmp:
```

But at this point I get stuck :

**ls: cannot access 'home/username/Maildir': no such file or directory**

Comment: What about `/home/username/Maildir`? With a leading `/`?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved mine by modifying the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file.
It seems like my hostname was not set correctly. I figured this out by looking a line : `myhostname = localhost.localdomain` . It should have been modified when i configured postfix but it didn't so, i modified it manually.

The process :

1 - type :

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

2 - Change line from :

```
myhostname = localhost.localdomain
```

to your domain name :

```
myhostname = example.com
```

3 - restart postfix :

```
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

Then try again.
Hope this will resolve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem until I changed the username in the documentation to what is specific to mine - `bitnami`. Username for some Ubuntu intallations are `ec2-user`, `admin`, `root`, etc. You need to confirm from your documentation.

Once you confirm the username, type this command at the prompt to re-adjust that setting in Postfix mail settings:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Then continue configuration from that point of the documentation. I hope that helps.